# Webkit reflow problem when dynamically changing border to DOM element

Tags: html, webkit, reflow

I have two div elements where one wraps around the other. Then I use JavaScript to add border to the outer div in runtime. Somehow webkit based browser doesn't do a reflow when the outer border is changed. The end result looks ugly - the inner div overflows the outer. Here is the HTML code:
[div id="outer][div id="inner" style="border: solid blue; height: 50px;"][/div][/div]

Event handler is simple as well: 
document.getElementById("outer").setAttribute("style", "border: solid green")

I couldn't believe it when I found this out since it's such a trivial reflow task. Or did I missing anything? Does anyone encounter similar problem, what's the workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry the HTML didn't show:

[div id="outer"][div id="inner" style="border: solid blue; height: 50px"][/div][/div]

Answer (score 0):

`border: solid green` Doesn't state *any* size, eg: `"border:1px solid green"`

I don't think it's safe to reset the entire `style` attribute because you might mess up some other things. Try adding a class to `className`, which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: "border: solid green" is a perfectly valid CSS statement. I don't get what you tried to say. Please answer my original question.

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the outer and inner to float:left it will work as planned.  However, you will either need to give it a fixed width or have content inside the div (inner).

```
#outer { float: left;}
#inner { float: left;}
```

[div id="outer"][div id="inner"]Text[/div][/div]

Comment: Floating the div does seem to trigger the reflow. I was doing "display: inline-block;" and it had similar effect. Additional markup is needed (clear the float or add line break etc.) to support these workarounds, which is ugly. I am just wondering why Webkit can't even handle such simple thing.